# Is it possible to use "cin" while referring to a pointer in structure?

Tags: c++, pointers, structure

This code is showing an error at the `cin` statement. Why is this?

Here is the error:

> no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::istream' {aka 'std::basic_istream<char>'} and 'int*')

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct go {
    int size, *p;
} r;

int main()
{
    int sum = 0;
    r.size = 10;
    r.p = (int*) malloc(r.size * sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i < r.size; i++){
        cin >> (r.p + i);   // this line is showing error
        sum = sum + (*(r.p + i));
    }
    cout << sum;
}
```

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/5910058)

Comment: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/5910058)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::istream` does not have an `operator>>` to read an `int*` pointer.  That is exactly what the error message is saying.

What you are really trying to do is read into the individual `int` elements of the array that you are allocating.  That means you need to deference the `int*` pointer so you can use the `operator>>` that reads an `int` value.  Just like you dereference the pointer when adding the `int` values to `sum`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

struct go {
    int size, *p;
} r;

int main()
{
    int sum = 0;

    r.size = 10;
    r.p = (int*) malloc(r.size * sizeof(int));
    // better: use new[] instead of malloc()
    // better: change r.p from int* to std::vector<int>, then use:
    // r.p.resize(r.size);

    for(int i = 0; i < r.size; i++){
        cin >> *(r.p + i); // or: cin >> r.p[i];
        sum += *(r.p + i); // or: sum += r.p[i];
    }

    cout << sum;

    free(r.p);
    // better: use delete[] instead of free()
    // better: let std::vector free the memory for you
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> This code is showing error at cin statement.Why is this so?

Because there is no overload of extracting a pointer from a character stream.

If you want to read into the pointed integer, simply indirect through the pointer:

```
std::cin >> r.p[i];
sum += r.p[i];
```

---

P.S. Avoid using `malloc` in C++, and avoid owning bare pointers. In this case, `std::vector` might be a better option.